# Idiomatic way to split string in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Is there a nicer/shorter/better way of performing the following:

```
filename = "AA_BB_CC_DD_EE_FF.xyz"
parts = filename.split("_")
packageName = "${parts[0]}_${parts[1]}_${parts[2]}_${parts[3]}"
//packageName == "AA_BB_CC_DD"
```

The format remains constant (6 parts, _ separator) but some of the values and lengths of AA,BB are variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same thing by just programming the "joining" part differently:

The following result in the same thing as `packageName`:

```
filename.split('_')[0..3].join('_')
```

It just uses a range to slice the array, and `.join` to concatenate with a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

As the separator char between the "segments" in the source filename and in the
result is the same (`_`), you don't need to split the filename and join the parts again.

Your task can be done with a single regex:

```
def result = filename.find(/([A-Z0-9]+_){3}[A-Z0-9]+/)
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned that some of the parts can be alpha and/or numeric.

Comment: No problem. Then `[A-Z]` should be changed to `[A-Z0-9]`.